# SQLServer.service Active is running but can`t connection (on CentOS8.3)

Tags: sql-server

When I run `systemctl status mssql-server.service`,there are no errors reported,Active is **active(running)**

```
 mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-11-18 10:16:13 CST; 32s ago
     Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux
 Main PID: 478033 (sqlservr)
    Tasks: 34
   Memory: 1.5G
   CGroup: /system.slice/mssql-server.service
           ├─478033 /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
           └─478037 /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr

11月 18 10:16:13 systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
11月 18 10:16:13 systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
11月 18 10:16:13 systemd[1]: Stopped Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.
11月 18 10:16:13 systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Found left-over process 478029 (sh) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
11月 18 10:16:13 systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
11月 18 10:16:13 systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Found left-over process 478031 (tar) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
11月 18 10:16:13 systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
11月 18 10:16:13 systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Found left-over process 478032 (bzip2) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
11月 18 10:16:13 systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
11月 18 10:16:13 systemd[1]: Started Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine.
```

but ,when I try to connect local service by sqlcmd `sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -p`
i got

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
```

understand, SQLServer has benn started, but can`t connect.

---

Another question, in the `/var/opt/mssql/log` path, generated many log file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAV7a.png)

Comment: If it's running then what address and port is it listening on? The `sqlcmd` that you're using doesn't specify a port number so it will only be trying to connect on port 1433. Depending on your network configuration that could be `::1:1433` (IPv6) instead of `127.0.0.1:1433` (IPv4).

Comment: You also seem to have issues with permissions... why are Microsoft SQL Server files owned by the `mysql` group?

Comment: I tried 127.0.0.1,1433 and it didn't work
Also, the user group is there by default and I haven't changed it